# Connections on RN42 v2

Tags: bluetooth, msp430

So a few months back, I asked about how to connect a RN42.  I finally built the circuit, which is basically a copy of the schematics on the right side of this pdf:

http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/BlueSMiRF-Gold-ChipAnt-v1_rotat2.pdf

I have RTS shorted to CTS, RX going to the TX pin (P1.4) of the MSP430, and TX going to the RX pin of the MSP430.  All the grounds (1, 12, 25, 27, 28, 29) connected to the common plane, pin 11 getting 3.3V, and a 10kohm resistor connected between pin 22 and ground.  The only difference is that I used 470 ohm resistors for the LEDs.

When I turn it on, nothing happens.  The status lights don't light up, windows bluetooth doesn't detect it at all. I've measured pin 11 and it is getting 3.3V input.  I'm stumped at what the problem may be.

Comment: A link to a datasheet for the module (as well as cct diagram) would be "useful". // Ensure that RTS/CTS is correctly enabled. // Place a standard AM radio against the powered on and enabled module. Tune across the whole band. You should hear one or more signals caused by the module even though the frequency is completely different. Try the same on the FM band BUT you will usually get much less there. Choose a strong output (probably on AM) and then try altering TXD and RTS. || What does pin 22 do?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Here is the datasheet for the RN42: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/rn-42-ds-v2.32r.pdf

I've actually solved the problem, it was a badly aligned module by the pcb fab house.  I did manage to fix it by realigning and resoldering the connections.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone was curious, there's actually no problems with my circuit.  The PCB fab house messed up my PCB.  Luckily, I have another copy of it that works fine...